# Configure npm to resolve dependencies using artifactory as proxy for both npm registry and github

Tags: github, npm, artifactory

I have a build server with no internet access, and I need to resolve dependencies from both github.com and registry.npmjs.org. The build server has access to Artifactory, so I have created an NPM repo to proxy for registry.npmjs.org and that is working, and I just created a VCS repo to proxy for github.com.

How can I configure npm to resolve from both of these? Since the 2 repos are different types, I can't aggregate them into a single virtual repo. Can NPM be configured to resolve dependencies from both of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VCS repos have zero correlation to NPM dependencies. A VCS repo is just a gateway to a set of APIs on the remote git server that will help you cache source binaries (i.e a zip/tarball of a particular branch/tag or even a release). The npm client is not familiar with the REST endpoints that Artifactory exposes for such repos.

For NPM packages that reference github repos inside their package.json (see URLs as dependencies & Git URLs as Dependencies sections [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)), you want to look into Artifactory's [dependency-rewrite mechanism](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-AutomaticallyRewritingExternalDependencies).

Since your NPM client is running on a machine that has no access to the internet, your own package.json files should not depend directly on "github dependencies", since these make the client bypass the registry configuration inside your ~/.npmrc and go directly to github instead of Artifactory.

When the package.json of one of your project's dependencies uses github dependencies, and this package is resolved via Artifactory, the dependency rewrite mechanism modifies the package.json on the fly before returning it to the client, so that subsequent dependency requests to resolve such dependencies are attempted via Artifactory, and not via github -- this is perfect for use cases such as yours.

In summary, you should stick with NPM repositories on Artifactory specifically, but also utilize the dependency rewrite mechanism of the Virtual Repository in order to avoid direct resolution of dependencies via github.

HTH,

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. It was indeed a dependency, not my own package.json, referencing github. I didn't realize that a full URL is used in the package.json for these github deps, so I assumed it was registered as another default repo or something when not found via registry.npmjs.org (I'm new to npm).