# Configure npm to resolve dependencies using JFrog Artifactory as proxy for both npm registry and GitHub

Tags: github, npm, artifactory

I have a build server with no internet access, and I need to resolve dependencies from both github.com and registry.npmjs.org. The build server has access to Artifactory(jfrog), so I have created an npm repo to proxy for registry.npmjs.org and that is working, and I just created dependency-rewrite mechanism under virtual repo for remote npm repo as mentioned in this link--[Configure npm to resolve dependencies using artifactory as proxy for both npm registry and github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645616/configure-npm-to-resolve-dependencies-using-artifactory-as-proxy-for-both-npm-re)
after configuring still I face the same issue:

```
node-sass@4.11.0 install /app/jenkins/workspace/uiwidget_smarthome1.0_dev/bwtk/node_modules/node-sass

node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-47_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-47_binding.node":
```

How can I configure npm to resolve from both of these? Since the 2 repos are different types, I can't aggregate them into a single virtual repo. Can npm be configured to resolve dependencies from both of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass the virtual repo url to the npm command. You can use ---registry virtual repo url or you can set the registry to using npm command

Comment: I had set the registry using npm command to virtual repo. virtual repo has dependency rewirte. After removing rewite and npm ssl set to false. It's working.

Comment: Okay, also in case you face any issues later on. Some npm packages during the installation doest send 200 OK response to artifactory hence artifactory fails the package installation. You can avoid such issues by setting the bypass proxy status in settings in artifactory

Comment: For now when I received 404 for specific package from artifactory.  I remove that specific package on artifactory. So that artifactory will fetch it again from registry. Thanks.